# JavaScript Operator Precedence, Assignment, and Increment?

Tags: javascript, operator-precedence, assignment-operator, order-of-execution, prefix-operator

In JavaScript (JS), `++` has higher precedence than `+=` or `=`. In trying to better understand operator execution order in JS, I'm hoping to see why the following code snippet results in `30` being printed?

```js
let i = 1
let j = (i+=2) * (i+=3 + ++i);
console.log(j); //prints 30
```

Naively, it seems like the `i+=2` is executing first, resulting in `3 * (i+=3 + ++i)`, and then `3` is being used as the starting value for `i` for both the `i+=3` and `++i` (resulting in `3 * (6 + 4)`). But I'm wondering, if that is the case, why either the `++i` or `i+=3` is not having its side effect in assigning to `i` occur before the other executes?

Comment: Your expression *might* have defined semantics in JavaScript, but using the same variable with two post-increment operations in the same larger expression is a very fragile way of writing code. Instead of knowing how it works, just don't do it. (I'm pretty sure that in C++ it's explicitly an undefined behavior.)

Comment: I mean, think about it. What if you saw that code in stuff you were trying to debug that was written 2 years ago? Just because you *can* do something doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the info; just trying to understand execution order in general as I am learning the language, and this was something I experimented with.

Comment: Well the problem is that in many languages trying to specify exactly how a weird expression like that will be evaluated interferes with efforts to optimize code that is *not* weird.

Comment: Weird thing: `(i+=2) * ((i+=3) + (++i))` yields `39`

Comment: To me it's best to step back and think, "What are the computational semantics I'm trying to express here? Why would I sit down with pencil and paper and dream up something like this?"

Comment: `(i+=3 + ++i)` is the same as `i += (3 + ++i)` not `(i+=3) + (++i)`

Comment: @Konrad ah, yes, I think that mostly explains it. Then you have `3 * (3 + (3 + 4))`, which relies on the execution order for the LHS `i` in `i += (3 + ++i)` I guess to be evaluated before the `++i` has its side-effect occur? I think that has to do with left-to-right execution order evaluating operands? Otherwise it would be `3 * (4 + (3 + 4))` which wouldn't yield `30`.

Comment: [Specs](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation)  confirm that left-hand side expression is evaluated first (look step 1) then the sum is calculated using that value (look step 7). So in your case `i+=3 + ++i` -> `i = 3 + 3 + ++i` where the first `3` is the value of `i` before the expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary of the discussion in comments:

Simplified example:

```js
let i = 1
let j = i += 3 + ++i;
console.log(j); //prints 6
```

`i += 3 + ++i` is the same as `i += (3 + ++i)` and not `(i += 3) + (++i)`

In the [ECMAScript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) we can read that left-hand side expression is evaluated first

> 1. Let lref be ? Evaluation of LeftHandSideExpression.

Then after right-hand side calculations in step `7`

> 7. Let r be ? ApplyStringOrNumericBinaryOperator(lval, opText, rval).

So `i += (3 + ++i)` is really:

```
let lhs = i // 1
let rhs = 3 + ++i // 3 + 2
i = lhs + rhs // 6
```

or in thee example from the question:

```
let lhs = i // 3
let rhs = 3 + ++i // 3 + 4
i = lhs + rhs // 10
```

Comment: another thing to consider is the parentheses of the first part. I don't think the confusion was with just the second part but with the whole expression. so for example if you do the original  `(i+=2) * (i+=3 + ++i)` it results in 30, but `i+=2 * (i+=3 + ++i)` results in 13